# Android: convert latin-1 to UTF8 nativley

Tags: android, utf-8

I have an RSS feed that is encoded with `iso-8859-1` which causes a lot of problems with [my parser](http://www.ingeniumblog.net/2012/01/making-a-slick-rss-reader-in-android/) in Android. Sometimes it will show as malformed data because it can't properly read a byte and will exit prematurely. I was able to setup a PHP script on my webserver that will convert the feed to UTF-8 with:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$utf8 = utf8_encode($str);
echo $utf8;
?>
```

It works great. However I wanted to make the app an independent entity so it will run whether I pay my bills or not. It also takes a noticeable speed hit with this process too.

**Is there a way I can utf-8 encode a latin-1 inputstream in Android?**

Answer (score 0):

PHP and Java are completely different this way, PHP strings are byte arrays, Java strings are real strings and Java has
separate mechanism for byte arrays. Your PHP solution only works if the RSS is in ISO-8859-1, you could probably improve that
by using Windows-1252 but it still doesn't work for actual UTF-8 RSS feeds.

So what you really need to change, is how you decode the response to a String in Android. You haven't shown the code for that. You would read
the Content-Type headers of the RSS feed or just enough to read the encoding attribute, or default to decoding as Windows-1252. Just like browsers do.

Comment: The full code I'm using is in the link "my parser" which implements a saxparser to decode the rss. The rss feed is out of my control so I couldn't change the encoding on that end.